# VESA not working on BOCHS

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bochs, vesa

I have written a simple bootloader which sets the video mode, and puts some pixels. I have tested it on Virtual box, QEMU, Dosbox and real hardware. Works great on them but not on Bochs. Mode sets correctly but pixels are not plotted.

```
 org 0x7c00

[BITS 16]           ;Tell Assembler to generate 16-bit code

jmp short start         ;Goto start, skip BIOS-Parameter-Block
nop             

;------------BIOS Parameter Block---------------;
;         Needed to recognize the disk      ;
;-----------------------------------------------;
OEMName:        db 'TEST OS '   ;Name of Orignal Equipment Manufacturer
bytesPerSector:     dw 512      ;Number of bytes in each sector
sectPerCluster:     db 1        ;Sectors in one cluster, 1 for FAT12
reservedCluster:    dw 1        ;1 sector is reserved for boot
totalFATs:      db 2        ;There are 2 fats in FAT12 these are copies of each other
rootDirEntries:     dw 224      ;Total entries (files or folders) in root directory
totalSectors:       dw 2880     ;Total Sectors in whole disk
mediaType:      db 0xf0     ;Media type 240 for floppies
sectorsPerFAT:      dw 9        ;Sectors used in on FAT
sectorsPerTrack:    dw 18       ;Sectors in one Track
totalHeads:     dw 2        ;Total sides of disk
hiddenSectors:      dd 0        
hugeSectors:        dd 0
driveNumber:        db 0        ;Drive Number 0 for A:\ floppy
            db 0
signature:      db 41       ;41 for floppies
volumeID:       dd 0        ;Any number
volumeLabel:        db 'TEST OS    ';Any 11-char name
fileSystem:     db 'FAT12   '   ;Type of file system on disk
;------------------------------------------------


;_______________________________________________

gdt:    dd 0x00000000,0x00000000 ;null descriptor
    dd 0x0000ffff,0x00cf9a00 ;code
    dd 0x0000ffff,0x00cf9200

gdtreg: dw 0x17          ;gdt size + 1
    dd 0             ;gdt base (latter filled)

start:
mov ax,0x4f01 ;get vesa mode info
mov cx,0115h ;video mode number
mov di,modeblock
int 0x10
mov esi, [modeblock+0x28] ;save linear frame buffer base = es:di+0x28

mov ax,0x4f02 ;set vesa mode
mov bx,0115h ;video mode number
int 0x10

mov ax,0x2401
int 0x15    ;enable a20 gate

xor eax,eax
mov ax,cs   
shl eax,4
mov [gdt+0x08+2],ax
shr eax,16
mov [gdt+0x20+4],al


xor eax,eax
mov ax,cs
shl eax,4
add eax,gdt
mov [gdtreg+2],eax
lgdt[gdtreg]

mov eax,cr0
or eax,1

cli
mov cr0,eax
jmp 0x08:pstart

[bits 32]
pstart:
mov eax,0x10
mov es,ax
mov ds,ax
mov fs,ax
mov ss,ax
mov gs,ax


cls:
mov eax,0xffffffff
mov edi, esi
mov ecx,1024*768*1/2
cld
rep stosd

;************ THIS PART IS NOT WORKING ON BOCHS. ************
main:
;test code
mov edi,esi 

mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0xff
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi

mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0xff
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi

mov byte[edi],0xff
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi  

mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0xff
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi

mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0xff
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi
mov byte[edi],0x00
inc edi

jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

modeblock:
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the return code in `AX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get linear framebuffer, you need to ask for it by setting bit #14 in `BX` register for the `4F02` function. Bochs seems to be picky about this and silently ignores writes if you haven't enabled the linear framebuffer:

```c
if (BX_VGA_THIS vbe.lfb_enabled)
{
...
}
else
{
    if (addr < BX_VGA_THIS vbe.base_address) {
      // banked mode write
      offset = (Bit32u)(BX_VGA_THIS vbe.bank*65536 + (addr - 0xA0000));
    }
    else {
      // LFB write while in banked mode -> ignore
      return;
    }
```

Also note that you should not hardcode mode numbers because they may be different on different systems. It's unclear what mode you want to set, bochs thinks `0x115` is 800x600x24, but your code has `1024*768*1/2` which hints that's not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use VESA VBE, you need to enable it in your bochsrc by setting the vga option to vbe.
http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/vesa-notes.html

vbe3.pdf from vesa.org

VBE RETURN STATUS

```
AL == 4Fh: Function is supported
AL != 4Fh: Function is not supported
AH == 00h: Function call successful
AH == 01h: Function call failed
AH == 02h: Function is not supported in the current hardware configuration
AH == 03h: Function call invalid in current video mode
```

The format of VBE mode numbers is as follows:

```
D0-D8 = Mode number
If D8 == 0, this is not a VESA defined VBE mode
If D8 == 1, this is a VESA defined VBE mode
D9-D12 = Reserved by VESA for future expansion (= 0)
D11 = Refresh Rate Control Select
If D11 == 0, Use current BIOS default refresh rate
If D11 == 1, Use user specified CRTC values for refresh rate
D12-13 = Reserved for VBE/AF (must be 0)
D14 = Linear/Flat Frame Buffer Select
If D14 == 0, Use Banked/Windowed Frame Buffer
If D14 == 1, Use Linear/Flat Frame Buffer
D15 = Preserve Display Memory Select
If D15 == 0, Clear display memory
If D15 == 1, Preserve display memory
```